Angular & ng-bootstrap - UI Questions
I am a UI design engineer and my team has decided to build out our site using Angular. Bootstrap is the preferred UI framework and this is our first endeavor into Angular.  I am seeing that ng-bootstrap is a popular method of using Bootstrap because of potential conflicts with jquery and DOM manipulation. However, I notice that ng-bootstrap is missing a number of widgets we would want to leverage (tabs, slider, date/search form fields, etc). In it's earlier years, as UI Bootstrap, some widgets were available that aren't in ng.
Are these missing widgets less likely to cause conflict and used in traditional ways? Or do you guys custom build them out as needed?
Researching links, not getting all the answers. Would like to know what I am getting into before making a decision.

Ng- Bootstrap does not include all the desired widgets. That's why generally, We should use combination of available libraries. For tab/search/..., you should use angular material along with ng-bootstrap
